# Is immigration/customs advice specific to pilots on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

[Does a Mexican citizen studying in the US with an FAA license need a visa when landing at airports in Canada?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14066/does-a-mexican-citizen-studying-in-the-us-with-an-faa-license-need-a-visa-when-l)

Some would say that this question is asking for *travel* advice, not *aviation* advice -- but for reasons that are fairly clear to me (scheduled international flight crews!), I suspect most countries deal with licensed pilots somewhat differently from an immigration standpoint...so is this on-topic, or should this be kicked over to travel.SE?

Comment: Related main site question: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5178/do-crew-need-visas-when-landing-at-airports-in-countries-other-than-their-own?rq=1

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `most countries deal with licensed pilots somewhat differently from an immigration standpoint`

Comment: @rbp -- not in terms of *permanent* immigration, no.  They do have special visa rules in many places for the reason I already stated, though... (also see Lnafzinger's comment on the answer to this question).

Comment: people from countries who need visas still need visas. being a pilot doesn't excuse you from needing one, so I don't consider that special treatment anymore than any other visa.

Comment: @rbp -- I'd have to look into it in more detail, but I'd expect them to be eligible for different types of visas than an ordinary traveler in jurisdictions where typed visas are used.

Comment: so what? a refugee needs a visa. someone who wants to work in the USA needs a visa. crew members need a visa. immigrants need a visa. tourists need a visa. there is no such thing as a "general visa" -- they are either all special treatment, or none of them are.

Comment: @rbp -- For the US, see [8 USC 1251](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-8057.html#0-0-0-288) and friends for special provisions applicable to foreign aircrews flying into the US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember, we are asked to be greedy with migration - to migrate only when the question is off-topic on the origin site. In the absence of Travel.SE, I think this question would not get closed as off-topic, as it is reasonably closely related to flying. Therefore, I believe we should **not migrate** this question.

Comment: Also of note is that, as he sort of stated in his question, a person acting as a flight crewmember often falls under different rules and visa requirements, so Travel.SE might not even be able to answer the question.